# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync thinks primary key should be INT when it is a GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

ASPNet, EF, SQL Server and .net 4.5

When I attempt to login to my web app the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync has decided that the key of the AspNetUsers table should have an INT primary key it is actually a nvarchar.

Any idea how the nature of the AspNetUsers primary key is specified so I can declare it as an nvarchar?

Comment: By default the Primary Key of ASP.NET Identity User is a string not a int.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I agree. Every once in a while though the PasswordSignInAsync function believes it should be an Int. Then on a refresh it forgets this and goes back to nvarchar. Today it is absolutely sure it should be an INT and is therefore blocking logins. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, have you change the primery key to int and now you want to change it back?

Comment: can you share your code, so everyone can understand the problem...

Comment: The database field is set to "Id (PK, nvarchar(128), not null)" it has always been that but occasionally the PasswordSignInAsync function decideds the field should be an Int.

Answer (score 0):

@Darem is right that the default Primary Key of ASP.NET Identity User is a string.
@Warwick I think you might be getting some error and you are guessing that it should be due to integer type primary key, but I suggest you that this can never happen.I am sharing my code for SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync function, might be it can help you.
So here is a working code:-

```
 public async Task<String> Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, int AgencyId)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(userName);
        if (AgencyId == user.AgencyId)
        {
            var loginrole = IdentityHelper.GetRoleName(userName);
            if (loginrole=="Administrator")
            {
                var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        return "Success";

                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                        return "Invalid email or password";

                    default:
                        return "Invalid email or password";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        return "Success";

                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        UserManager.SetLockoutEndDate(user.Id, new DateTime(9999, 12, 30));
                        return "Your account has been locked, Please contact administrator.";

                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                        return "Invalid email or password";

                    default:
                        return "Invalid email or password";
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Agency";
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you are still facing any issue.
All the best.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. I agree it should be a string But the PasswordSignInAsync keepings throwing a convert to Int exception. It should not be happening.

Comment: Check if the database aspnetuser table has nvarchar(128) datatype for primary key field in SQL Server. If it is true then update your edmx and try to login. If there is still the same error then issue is in code, which means that we are not using PasswordSignInAsync in a proper way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Using Code First not EDMX, and the field is set as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

from @sharptooth
In attempting to resolve a very similar error (Unable to cast object of type system.guid to type system.string) for the same scenario, I traced the problem to the data types that had been used for the key columns of two Roles tables (AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles). These needed to be of type nvarchar, not uniqueidentifier.

The SQL query behind PasswordSignInAsync gathers data from AspNetUsers, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserClaims and AspNetUserLogins so I suggest you check that your key column types across all of these tables match what the expected entities that this data will be mapped to. As far as I'm aware, these should be as follows:

AspNetUsers > [Id] NVARCHAR (128)

AspNetRoles > [Id] NVARCHAR (128)

AspNetUserRoles > [UserId] NVARCHAR (128), [RoleId] NVARCHAR (128)

AspNetUserClaims > [Id] INT

AspNetUserLogins > [UserId] NVARCHAR (128)